# PDFKit PDFThumbnailView thumbnails not centred

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, thumbnails

I am displaying PDF files in the Detail of a SplitViewController with thumbnails in a PDFThumbnailView as shown here.

[image: PDFThumbnailView]

The PDFThumbnailView has a green background.

The problem I am having is that the first page thumbnail appears to be central to the PDFThumbnailView and for longer PDF documents runs over on the right.

[image: PDFThumbnailView2]

I would preferably like the thumbnails to be left-aligned in the view or else centred on the middle page of the pdf document.

I have tried setting the contentInsets but to no avail.

```
let edgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5.0, left: 5.0, bottom: 5.0, right: 5.0)
pdfThumbnailView.contentInset = edgeInsets
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

For some reason after switching several times between PDF documents the thumbnails adjust themselves correctly although problem recurs on re-running the App.

[image: PDFThumbnailView3]

Any help anyone?

Comment: How did you add this thumbnail view to the bottom? did you use any pods?

Answer (score 0):

```
let edgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5.0, left: 5.0, bottom: 5.0, right: 5.0)
pdfThumbnailView.contentInset = edgeInsets
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

[@user3425784](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3425784/user3425784)

You have to set the constraint for PDFThumbnailView like below and its working fine for me.

```
  let thumbnailView = PDFThumbnailView()
  thumbnailView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
  self.viewForPDFThumb.addSubview(thumbnailView)

  thumbnailView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    thumbnailView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    thumbnailView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    self.PdfView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: thumbnailView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    thumbnailView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true

    thumbnailView.thumbnailSize = CGSize(width: 70, height: 80)
    thumbnailView.layoutMode = .horizontal
    thumbnailView.pdfView = self.PdfView
```